# Vue3 watching Vuex4 store doesn't run callback function

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I just started with Vue 3 and I'm trying to observe a state change on the store, which is built with Vuex.

For some reason it is not working as intended.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMounted, computed, watch } from 'vue';
    import { useStore } from 'vuex';

    import LineDrawer from '../helper/LineDrawer';

    export default {
      setup() {
        const store = useStore();
        const lines = computed(() => store.state.lines.length);

         onMounted(() => {
           new LineDrawer();

           setTimeout(() => store.commit('push'), 1000);
          });

          watch(() => lines, () => {
           console.log('lines changed');
          });

          return {
            lines,
          };
     },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: do the answers below help you?

Answer (score 3):

The `watch` function can take a `ref` as an argument and `computed` returns a reactive `ref`.

[**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8t5u3khg/)

```js
// ...

        watch(lines, () => console.log('lines changed'));

// ...
```

Comment: You could just add `{deep:true}` like `watch(lines, () => console.log('lines changed'),{deep:true});`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're watching an array you should add `{deep:tree}` option  :

```
  watch(() => lines, () => {
       console.log('lines changed');
      },{
        deep:true
     });
```